# Binding to the minimize/maximize buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a `tkinter.Toplevel` widget where I'd like to bind to the maximize button, i.e. perform my own action when the user clicks on the little + button on the top of the window. Anybody know how to do this? Is there a way to do this with `protocol`, or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

For minimization you should be able to bind to `<UnMap>` You can read more [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm#M13).

I'm not sure what to suggest for maximization.  Maybe the `<Configure>` event, or `<ResizeRequest>`.